# Access 2007 form with SQL Server 2008 backend working with images

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a situation where I'm using MS Access 2007 for forms, queries and reports, and SQL Server 2008 as the back-end holding data.

The idea is that the database will be on a server and connected to clients (Access forms) via a LAN.
Now I need to store images to the database through the Access form and display them also on a form, other clients should be able to view these pictures on their forms.

I've tried making a `varbinary(MAX)` field in SQL Server with different form controls in access but it was too complicated for the user to choose the image file and it didn't display the picture on the form as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly advise against storing images as columns in your database.  Store them on a network machine and then save the folder address.  Give each of your images that you save a unique name.  In your instance, have the names be descrptive of what the actual images are (since it sounds like the system is designed for internal users only).  Large public sites like Facebook or Twitter store image names as long random strings to prevent unauthorized users from snooping.  Ever time you save an image on your local drive, insert its name into your database.  You'll now have a link between your database (which stores the images' metadata) and the actual images themselves.

More info in this [thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=564251#post564251)

Comment: That worked, Just added some extra code, a bit tiring but it's a very good work around, thanks a lot :)